# Different responses when using Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: api, matrix, distance, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I have two postcodes (A) and (B) and I am seeing different distances and durations between A to B and B to A and while this matches the Google Maps website, we have seen the distance and duration between A to B in that direction change from one day to the next.

I don't believe the API request URL is set to include traffic so I don't know why Google has altered the primary preferred route between when we first ran this request and the second request.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I did my research and I found that both Distance Matrix API and Directions API alters their duration_in_traffic value for my requests with periods which is about 30 seconds. It just gives me 1 of 2 possible values with difference of couple seconds. So obvious solution is API response local caching.